# wp_query custom post type by taxonomy & standard post by taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

Anyone know how I can neatly combine a query to pull CPT by a custom taxonomy and also standard posts by taxonomy into same query to list all posts together on my home page?

for example:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'           => array( 'artists', 'post' ),
    'post_status'         => 'publish',
    'tag_artists'         => 'home', // cpt custom taxonomy ##
    'tag'                 => 'home', // standard post type taxonomy ##
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

This is clearly wrong as it finds zero results..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the answer:

```
$args = array(
'post_type'     => array( 'artists', 'post' ),
'post_status'   => 'publish',
'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'tag_artists',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => array( 'home' )
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => array( 'home' )
    )
)
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```